# How do I get Facebook access token in iOS UIwebview?

Tags: facebook, ios5

Hi I am still noobie of iOS development, I got stuck with this problem.
I made a app which uses facebook account. and there is a link which opens safari app and goes to facebook page. However I want that link to have the facebook account so that when the safari app is opened the facebook page is already logged in with the setting from my app.

also I tried this
    NSString *accessToken = [[FBSession activeSession] accessToken]; 
but it gets null

can someone help this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to send the safari app a "Log the user in with facebook then go to the page" request. It's not possible.